# how to extract date from filename using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract date from `nd_OnePur_facts20180712_1514.tgz`

I tried the following code split the string and access the element. I looking out for regex to extract date

```
str="nd_OnePurchasing_dims20180712_1200.tgz"
str2=re.split("(_)+", str)
```

Comment: E.g. `re.search(r'\d{8}', s).group()`.

Comment: note that `str` is a protected keyword in python